# jQuery on click event to scrollToTop then redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This might be an easy one - but I can't seem to get my head around this one. I have a funky navbar which is animated and I want a quick scrollToTop when a navbar href is clicked - then I want to redirect to that href. This is what I have this far, which doesn't quite work.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    });

        $('.scrollup').click(function () {
          $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
          }, 600, function() {
             var baseurl = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname;
             $(location).delay(800).attr('href', baseurl + this.getAttribute('href'));
          });
       return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is the base html relevant to the navbar if anyone needs that:

```
<!-- Sticky Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
    <!-- Toggle Button -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <!-- /Toggle Button -->

    <!-- Center Menu -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-top navbar-left">
            <!-- <li class="active">
                <a class="animated-menu-item" href="#">Home</a>
            </li> -->
            <li>
                <a class="animated-menu-item scrollup" href="/our-wines">OUR WINES</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="animated-menu-item" href="/about-us">ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-top navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a class="animated-menu-item" href="/latest">LATEST</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="animated-menu-item" href="/contact">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /Center Menu -->
</nav>
```

Comment: so there is an event when animation is done

Comment: @epascarello Hi. Yeh, just a basic redirect...ideally done by grabbing href. Hopefully my question was clear - if not feel free to ask as many questions as you need.

Comment: that's not what delay is for.

Comment: @KevinB I completely missed adding that to my answer, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clicking on a link, we can break the function into three main parts for readability:

1. Stopping the default action of the link and getting the URL
2. Running the animation
3. Going to the link URL

Below is a working example of what it should look like, I have commented above the relevant parts:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link').click(function(e){

        //stop the link from immediately working
        e.preventDefault();
        
        //get the link href
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        
        //do your animation
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
        
        //wait 600 ms and redirect to the URL we grabbed earlier
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            window.location = href;
        }, 600, href);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>
```

Keep in mind that the redirect isn't going to work from inside the snippet, you will most probably have to test this in your environment, but I did have this exact code in a temp index.html file and it worked just fine.

**EDIT:**

Following up on KevinB's comment, `.delay()` won't work in this instance as it is used to queue events in the *standard effects* queue. As per the [jQuery API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited — it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay — .delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.